# コンパイルエラーの内容及び解決方法について。

Tags: c++, spresense

コンパイルが通りません。別のパソコンでは通ったのですが、同じ設定で動かすとコンパイルが通らなくなりました。エラーを読みましたが、よくわからず質問した次第です。
環境

OS：ubuntu18.04
IDE:VScode
動作確認している環境も同じものです。

当方、spresense初心者でして、理解及ばぬところあるかと思いますが、ご指導いただけると幸いです。

```
LD: nuttx 
arm-none-eabi-ld: /home/hogehoge/spresense/nuttx/staging/libapps.a(symtab_apps.o):(.rodata.g_exports+0x2cc): undefined reference to `system' 
Makefile:155: recipe for target 'nuttx' failed 
make[2]: *** [nuttx] Error 1 
make[2]: ディレクトリ '/home/hogehoge/spresense/nuttx/arch/arm/src' から出ます 
tools/Makefile.unix:420: recipe for target 'nuttx' 
failed make[1]: *** [nuttx] Error 2 
make[1]: ディレクトリ '/home/hogehoge/spresense/nuttx' から出ます
Makefile:113: recipe for target 'all' failed 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: `system` が undefined reference 未定義参照らしいので, リンク時のライブラリーに加える必要がありそうです。けれど, `Makefile`など自動生成しているのなら開発環境ごとに再作成(開発環境に合わせて構築)する必要があるはず

Comment: [コンフィグレーション手順](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ja.html#_コンフィグレーション手順) のような手順があると思うけど, 対象のマシンで行いましたか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。やったことといたしましては、
make discleanにてクリーンアップ。
再度、SDKのコンフィグ。
プロジェクトの設定等。
makeでビルド
です。しかし同じくエラーが出ました。

Comment: ２つの PC でコンパイル環境は完全に同一ですか？ (各ツールのバージョン等) / 何が一緒で何が違うのかをチェックしていくと問題点のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: ツールのバージョン等まったく同じものを使用しています。

Answer (score 3):

リンクエラーの内容から推察するに、`System Command`を有効にしていない状態で`system()`関数を使用したローダブルELFアプリケーションをビルドしているのではないかと思います。

`menuconfig`で以下の`System Commmand (CONFIG_SYSTEM_SYSTEM)`を有効にしてからビルドしてみてください。

```
-> Application Configuration
 -> System Libraries and NSH Add-Ons
  [*] System Command
```

予想を外してたらすみません。

Comment: お返事遅くなり申し訳ありません。回答ありがとうございます。
SystemCommandにチェックをいれて無事動くようになりました。
ありがとうございます！

Comment: 予想が当たったみたいで、無事に解決して良かったです！承認マークを付けてもらえると嬉しいです^^

Answer (score 0):

利用コードはzip解凍のものでなく、gitで落としたものですか？
コマンドでgit submoduleで表示される情報は、両方同じになっていますかね？

もし異なっていればエラー出ている側のnuttxのコードが更新されていない可能性もあります。
その場合は、spresense.gitを落としたフォルダ以下で、以下のコマンドを打って、submoduleコードを更新してみてください。

```
$git submodule update --init
```

Comment: お返事遅くなり申し訳ありません。回答ありがとうございます。
更新はしてみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。こういうこともあるのかととても参考になりました。ありがとうございます。